# Maven profile filter works when building WAR but not in Tomcat7 run

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to use Maven to pull in a different config point within my web.xml file in dev and production. It looks like using profiles and filters is the way to go, and this does in fact work when I build the WAR file with "mvn install" or "mvn package." However, running it via the Tomcat 7 plugin, always results in a "cannot resolve placeholder" error. Here are the relevant lines:

in web.xml - this is the placeholder I'm trying to set

```
/WEB-INF/${sec-file-path}
```

in pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <properties>
            <sec-file-path>one-thing-for-dev.xml</sec-file-path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <sec-file-path>one-thing-for-prod.xml</sec-file-path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

....

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId> maven-war-plugin </artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/web.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Running the command  "mvn package -P development" works as expected and fills in the placeholder appropriately. However, running  "mvn tomcat7:run -P development" results results in a "cannot resolve placeholder" error. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have found similar behavior where running against mvn tomcat:run (Tomcat 6) would (seemingly) properly place the placeholder values but suddenly mvn tomcat7:run (Tomcat 7) would fail.

I think in all actuality, the Tomcat6 plugin was overstepping its bounds some and the Tomcat7 plugin is working properly.  (I am NOT an expert on Spring or Maven so take that statement with a large grain of salt.)

Spring files (applicationContext.xml) should get their placeholder values from property placeholder files and not the Maven filter process.

How you resolve this is using the placeholder values in Spring-controlled properties files instead of maven filter files.  You can still leverage your data that you have in your filters files, you just pass them through a properties file to get the job done.

**Set up filters as usual:**

*pom.xml*

```xml
<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/local.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
...
</build>
```

**Create your filter properties file:**

*src/main/filters/local.properties*

```
# Session
session.timeout=20
```

**Create your Spring placeholder properties file:**

*src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/timeout.properties*

```
# Session
spring.session.timeout = ${session.timeout}
```

**Finally, configure your placeholder in your application context:**

*src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml*

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-   context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<!--  Properties file for Session Configuration --> 
<context:property-placeholder location="/opt/Projects/workspace/application_server/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
...

<bean id="timeout.example" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <constructor-arg value="${spring.session.timeout}"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

When Maven runs its resources phase, the placeholder values in the timeout.properties file will be updated to the values it found in the local.properties file.

When the Spring process runs "later" (at the run phase) then it will interrogate the applicationContext.xml file to find the placeholders, which it will fill with the values it finds in the PlaceholderConfigured file (timeout.properties).

*(Note:  The variable names do not have to be different (e.g. spring.session.timeout vs. session.timeout).  I only did that here to differentiate the two.)*